# A simple vector problem

Tags: geometry, vectors

U, V, A, B are 2d vectors.
U*A=V*A and U*B=V*B 
When does U = V (I think that almost all the time except when A = B and other special cases)

Comment: What is the product $UA$ for two vectors ? Is it the dot product ?

Comment: U*A*cos(U;A) as always!

Comment: Seriously it is unknown. Only thing we know is the two equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W=U-V$.  Then $W.A=0=W.B$  If $A$ is not a multiple of $B$, then $\cos(W;A)$ and $\cos(W;B)$ can't both be zero, so $|W|=0$; so $W=0$, so $U=V$.
If $A=kB$ then $W$ is just perpendicular to $A$ (and to $B$).  In  this case, $A$ and $B$ either point in the same direction; or in exactly opposite directions.
$A=0$ is an example of $A=kB$, so $U$ doesn't have to equal $V$ in this case either.